# How to access Twitter OAuth token once page got refresh?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Following Firebase documentation on [Twitter Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/twitter-login) we get to something like this:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.4/firebase-app.js">    </script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.4/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script>
    // NOTE: pseudo code
    // initialise the app
    firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: "API_KEY",
        authDomain: "AUTH_DOMAIN",
        databaseURL: "DATABASE_URL",
        projectId: "PROJECT_ID",
        storageBucket: "STORAGE_BUCKET",
        messagingSenderId: "MESSAGING_SENDER_ID"
    });

    // create Twitter provider
    provider = new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();

    // auth with popup
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
    // in theory we could now access the OAuth token so we can make further requests to the Twitter API.
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    var secret = result.credential.secret;
});
```

So far all good. We can access the token and secret and make any request to the twitter API.

Also on the documentation there's reference to the `firebase.auth().currentUser` method which we can call after a page refresh (for example).
In this object we have access to some information previously obtained when we first login, however we can't access the OAuth Token nor the secret.

There's further documentation regarding Auth State persistence where some other methods are mention like `firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)` which I think its what I need. However I still can't access the Token nor the secret.

Am I suppose to store it in a cookie or localStorage entry when the user first logs in? Is this even secure? Any help would be appreciated as I don't want to force my users to login to twitter every time they close the site and open it again.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Auth doesn't manage 3rd party OAuth tokens. They only return the OAuth tokens on sign in and discard them afterwards. They don't store these data so you will not be able to get them after sign in unless you store them locally. Firebase Auth is currently only focused on providing an AuthN solution and not AuthZ.